# Will the Driver Support for Intel HD Graphics be Improved in 12.10?

Tags: display, 12.10, vga, nomodeset

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP Pavilion dv4 laptop. This is a core i7 machine with Intel HD graphics and also a separate nVidia VGA card. I had a lot of issues getting Ubuntu 12.04 working on this system. First there were issues booting up the live CD for installation. I worked around that by using the 'nomodeset' option. Then I continued to have similar issues after installation has completed. So I had to permanently add the nomodeset option to my GRUB boot configuration. At the moment I have a working installation but there are many issues:

1. Ubuntu GUI is a bit flaky at times. The mouse pointer goes on and off when hovering over certain icons. Certain things doesn't get rendered properly on the screen.
2. I can't access any of the tty consoles. Hitting Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] gives me a blank screen. And once that happens I can't even come back to the UI by hitting Ctrl+Alt+F7. I've realized that tty consoles are actually working. I just can't see the text. If I enter a command like 'sudo reboot' into the empty screen the machine reboots.
3. Can't get external displays (monitors, projectors etc) working. But I think this is probably because the VGA out is wired to the nVidia card which is not being used by Linux.
4. colord program crashes every now and then triggering a popup message.

So my main question is, will the support for Intel HD graphics be improved in the next release? Or will I have to keep using the nomodeset option in the new release too? Also I  appreciate if anybody can shed some light on any of the issues listed above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Not sure about the specific bugs you hit, but it will be improved.

The Linux kernel and X.org drivers will receive quite some updates in the upcoming release. Try out some backports for the current release from the [X Updates PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) (only X and graphics) or [xorg-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) (bleeding edge, new 3.5 kernel, may break everything).

Also if you update 12.04 completely (aka 12.04.1 at this moment), support should also be better than at the time of the 12.04 release.

I suggest the [Phoronix article category "Display Drivers"](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=category&item=Display%20Drivers) for further readings.